# collapsing a cube by subtracting dimensions

Tags: arrays, numpy

I have a cube that contains the probability density based on 3 variables of the shape [t1,t2,gamma] with 80 values in each direction. I need to plot the distribution of T, gamma. Where T is t2-t1.

Is there some clever way to collapse this cube into the desired result? I've been breaking my head on it and I can't find one.

Comment: What are the expected output dimensions of this result?  Can you show us a sample calculation using a smaller cube of say, 3 x 3 x 3 dimensions?  If you do this for a smaller sample set, it will put us (and even you) in the right direction on what is to be achieved.

Comment: if t1 and t2 are independent, you can generate a matrix t1-gamma, another t2-gamma, then substract them, and then create the cube with `meshgrid`

Comment: which language are you working in?

Answer (score 0):

You can pad with zeros and then shear the array by incrementing or decrementing a dimension by one:

```
# make small diagnostic example
nt1, nt2, ngm = 4, 5, 2
data = sum(np.ogrid[1:nt1+1,-1:-nt2-1:-1,100:100*ngm+100:100])
# by construction values are equal if coordinates (T,gamma) are equal, no matter how T = t2-t1 decomposes.
# Fixing gamma, for example at 1, we can see that T is constant along the diagonals
data[..., 1]
# array([[200, 199, 198, 197, 196],
#        [201, 200, 199, 198, 197],
#        [202, 201, 200, 199, 198],
#        [203, 202, 201, 200, 199]])

# now let's transform the example, first recover dimensions
nt1, nt2, ngm = data.shape
# next, zero pad
aux = np.zeros((nt1+2, nt1+nt2-2, ngm), data.dtype)
aux[1:-1, :nt2] = data
# and shear, in this case by incrementing dimension 1
sheared = aux.reshape(-1, ngm)[nt2-1:3-nt1-nt2].reshape(nt1, nt1+nt2-1, ngm)

# check result, for example at gamma = 1
sheared[..., 1]
# array([[  0,   0,   0, 200, 199, 198, 197, 196],
#        [  0,   0, 201, 200, 199, 198, 197,   0],
#        [  0, 202, 201, 200, 199, 198,   0,   0],
#        [203, 202, 201, 200, 199,   0,   0,   0]])


# corresponding values of T are now aligned and ready for further processing.
```